# where can I learn about the C++ instance keyword?

Tags: c++, instance, keyword

In a program I'm maintaining I found a class with the keyword instance at the end of it. Like so:

```
class SomeClass{ 
public:
} instance;
```

The program is a DLL, and this "SomeClass" is the first object created when loading the DLL. Where does the instance keyword come from? Is it specific to gcc? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: That's *not* a keyword, it is the identifier of a instance of the class declared. That is equivalent to writing `class SomeClass{...}; SomeClass instance;`.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax of a struct or class definition is something like this:

(`class` | `struct`) [class tag] `{` *members* `}` *instances* `;`

I'm using `[` and `]` to signify an optional item and italics to signify an arbitrary list of items.

In other words, you can define just the type itself, something like:

```
 class xxx { /* ... */ };
```

...or you can define just an instance like:

```
 class { /* ... */ } an_instance;
```

...or you can do both:

```
 class xxx { /* ... */ } another_instance;
```

...or you can define a number of instances, if you want:

```
 class xxx { /* ... */ } instance1, instance2, instance3;
```

The latter aren't keywords though -- they're just normal variables. Most people who wanted to accomplish the same thing would probably write the two separately:

```
class SomeClass { 
   /* ... */
};

SomeClass instance;
```

For most practical purposes, this is synonymous with the form in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The word `instance` isn't a keyword.  You're instantiating a class object of type `SomeClass` called `instance`.

Here is [a list of C++ Keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) I found from a Google search.